# CASE expression in ListAgg()

Tags: sql, oracle, case, listagg

I am including a ListAgg in my query using a case expression.

However I keep receiving the error "missing keyword." I've used the format I've found in other answers here, but it still isn't working.

```
    Select
    SC.NAME,
    listagg(case sc.COURSE_REFERENCE_NUMBER
    when  sc.department = 'AVSC' and sc.course_number in ('100', '200', 
    '300', '400') end, ', ')
    within group (order by sc.COURSE_REFERENCE_NUMBER) as avsc_crn

    from odsmgr.student_course SC
    where SC.ACADEMIC_PERIOD = '201990'
```

The exact message is:

> Server error number: 003000
>   OraOLEDB : ORA-00905: missing keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `case` syntax is off.  You need a `then` clause:

```
listagg(case when  sc.department = 'AVSC' and sc.course_number in ('100', '200', '300', '400')
             then sc.COURSE_REFERENCE_NUMBER
         end, ', ') within group (order by sc.COURSE_REFERENCE_NUMBER) as avsc_crn
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd been staring at it for so long, I missed the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The CASE statement is syntactically wrong.
I think that what you want is this:

```
case 
    when sc.department = 'AVSC' and sc.course_number in ('100', '200', '300', '400') 
      then sc.COURSE_REFERENCE_NUMBER
end
```

Maybe you need to add an ELSE part:

```
case 
    when sc.department = 'AVSC' and sc.course_number in ('100', '200', '300', '400') 
      then sc.COURSE_REFERENCE_NUMBER
    else ....
end
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you have not the THEN  condition for  sc.COURSE_REFERENCE_NUMBER

```
Select
  SC.NAME,
  listagg(
    case   when  sc.department = 'AVSC' and sc.course_number in ('100', '200', 
  '300', '400')  THEN sc.COURSE_REFERENCE_NUMBER end, ', ')
  within group (order by sc.COURSE_REFERENCE_NUMBER) as avsc_crn
  from odsmgr.student_course SC
  where SC.ACADEMIC_PERIOD = '201990'
```